# make: *** [Makefile:2449: modules] Error 2 while trying to install a wifi adapter driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, make, additional-drivers, d-link

```
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/driver/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.13.1-20 <br/>gbd7c7eb9d_COEX20210316-18317b7b.20210702/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.13.1-20-<br/>gbd7c7eb9d.20210702_COEX20210316-18317b7b/core/rtw_br_ext.c:20:11: fatal error: net/ipx.h: No such file or directory<br/>
   20 |  #include <net/ipx.h><br/>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~<br/>
compilation terminated.<br/>
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/driver<br/>/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.13.1-20-gbd7c7eb9d_COEX20210316-18317b7b.20210702/driver<br/>/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.13.1-20-gbd7c7eb9d.20210702_COEX20210316-18317b7b/core/rtw_br_ext.o] Error 1<br/>
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1906: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/driver/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.13.1-20-<br/>gbd7c7eb9d_COEX20210316-18317b7b.20210702/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.13.1-20-<br/>gbd7c7eb9d.20210702_COEX20210316-18317b7b] Error 2<br/>
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-67-generic'<br/>
make: *** [Makefile:2449: modules] Error 2<br/>
##################################################<br/>
Compile make driver error: 2<br/>
Please check error Mesg<br/>
##################################################<br/>
<br/>
```

I have used this command: `sudo apt install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-generic`
but it did not solve the problem

you can only find the driver itself in [here](https://www.dlink.ru/ru/products/2/2432.html) (Russian page)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

edit: the solution found by Denatunium
was to downgrade the kernel https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-the-5-4-lts-version/26459

the below solution exist if it is still not working

It look like a missing `ipx.h` header file

Do the following to try to fix your problem:

first install the missing header file

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

then clean the driver source code

```
cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/driver/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.13.1-20-gbd7c7eb9d_COEX20210316-18317b7b.20210702
make clean
```

then rebuild the driver

```
make
```

then install

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added a screenshot of the directory content, make clean will lead to: make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.

Comment: What kernel version are you testing this on? It looks like the file has been dropped since 5.15 - see for example [commit 6c9b40844751ea30c72f7a2f92f4d704bc6b2927](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/include/net?id=6c9b40844751ea30c72f7a2f92f4d704bc6b2927)

Comment: @steeldriver its 5.15.0-67-generic

Comment: @steeldriver what should I do? maybe downgrade my Linux to a version that has  net/ipx.h and uapi/linux/ipx.h header files ??

Comment: yes im on 5.15 but I have not tried to install the driver

Comment: In this Case, downgrading the kernel Solved the Issue, I also used [This tutorial](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-the-5-4-lts-version/26459) to downgrade the kernel
please edit your answer if you think there is a need to and if its possible, Thankyou. @Saxtheowl

Comment: @Denatunium Done